# how to program php signup page with ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, smarty

i have this ajax function:

```
function getpage(page,div){
var url = page+"&sid="+Math.random();
    var xhr; 
    try {  xhr = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');   
    }
    catch (e) 
    {
        try {   xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');    
        }
        catch (e2) 
        {
          try {  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();     
          }
          catch (e3) {  
          xhr = false;   
          }
        }
     }

    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function()
    { 
         if(xhr.readyState  == 4){
              if(xhr.status  == 200)
                document.getElementById(div).style.display= "block";
                document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = xhr.responseText; 
         }else{
                document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = '<img src="./pic/load.gif" />';
         }
    }; 

   xhr.open( "GET", url,  true); 
   xhr.send(null); 
}
```

and i have singup form (designed with smarty templates):

```
<div><input style="width:300px" class="inp" type="text" onkeyup="getpage('./ajax.php?action=regnewuser&usern={$uname}','register')" name="User_name"  placeholder="username" required /></div><div class="hr" id="register"></div>
```

and I have this ajax.php code:

```
if($act == 'regnewuser'){
            $usern   = protect($_GET['usern']);

        $sql = $db->query("SELECT USER_NAME FROM ".$pre."USERS");
            while($row = $db->record()){
            $dbuname = strtolower($row['USER_NAME']);
            $uname2  = strtolower($usern);
            }
        if(empty($usern)){
            echo '<div class="rd">please fill the box !!</div>';
        }elseif(strlen($usern) < 4){
            echo '<div class="rd">too short !!</div>';
        }elseif(strlen($usern) > 50){
            echo '<div class="rd">too tall !!</div>';
        }elseif($dbuname == $uname2){
            echo '<div class="rd">not available !!</div>';
        }
    }
```

but the result always "please fill the box";

I think the problem in the template form !

 what i should to but into template to get correct result??

Answer (score 0):

What is `{$uname}` intended to do in your `onkeyup` code?

Looks like PHP code to me.

You need to use JavaScript to append the username to the URL. If you were to set an `id` attribute on the `input` element of `id` the code to generate the URL would be:

```
var url = "/ajax.php?action=regnewuser&usern=" + document.getElementById("username").value();
```

I would suggest doing this in a seperate function and passing the generated URL to your `getpage` function.

That said I'm not sure `onkeyup` is the right event to attach your code to. Do you really want to create a user record everytime a key is pressed in the text box?

For example if a user typed 'test' do you want 4 records creating? ('t','te','tes','test')

I would suggest adding a button for the user to click once they have finished populating the text box and are happy (attach your code to the `onclick` event of the button).

Comment: $uname   = protect($_POST['User_name']);

Comment: i want to create code if i registed username was wrong(short or tall or registed befor) give me msg beside input box that i entered wrong username without pressing submit button